# How do you define the monad instance for the following data types?

Tags: haskell, expression, monads, environment, applicative

Here's the code I have to work with:

```
infixl 9 :@: -- This is newly defined symbol used in the application of expressions

data Expr
  =  Lit Integer      -- a literal
  |  Var String       -- a variable
  |  Bin Expr Op Expr -- binary operator
  |  Abs String Expr  -- a lambda expression
  |  Expr :@: Expr    -- an application
  deriving Show

data Op = Plus | Mult
  deriving Show

data Value = IntVal Integer | FunVal Env String Expr
  deriving Show

type Env = [(String,Value)]

applyIntOp :: Op -> Value -> Value -> Value
applyIntOp op (IntVal v1) (IntVal v2) = 
   case op of 
      Plus -> IntVal (v1 + v2)
      Mult -> IntVal (v1 * v2)

eval :: Expr -> Env -> Value
eval (Lit i)        env = IntVal i
eval (Var v)        env = fromJust (lookup v env)
eval (Bin e1 op e2) env = applyIntOp op (eval e1 env) (eval e2 env)
eval (Abs v b)      env = FunVal env v b
eval (ef :@: ea)    env = let FunVal env var body = eval ef env
                              arg                 = eval ea env
                           in eval body ((var,arg):env)
```

The goal is to make an evaluation function such that it can use variables (Var String), of which the variables are taken from the environment (Env). However when I try to define a monad with any of these types, I can't because they don't have the correct kind (* instead of * -> *).

So, how would I go about defining this Monad such that I can use it to evaluate any expressions correctly.

```
instance Monad ? where
  return = ..
  >>=    = ..
```

As an example (3 + (x * 4)(apply)(x=1+2)):

```
eval (Bin (Lit 3) Plus ((Abs "x" (Bin (Var "x") Mult (Lit 4))) :@: Bin (Lit 1) Plus (Lit 2))) []
```

This returns 15

Comment: The first step is to make sure you type *has* the right kind: `data Expr a = ...` Only then does it even make sense to define `Functor`, `Applicative`, and `Monad` instances for `Expr`. However, you still have to think about what it would *mean* for your type to have a `Monad` instance. As a simple example, what do you think `f >>= Lit 3` should mean?

Comment: First of all, thanks for responding. I am confused about how somebody would add the polymorphic 'a' to a data type without it being useless.
Secondly, does f >>= Lit 3 mean Lit f a?

Comment: @chepner `Lit 3 >>= f`, surely.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you're trying to add a monad instance?  You already have a working `eval`, so what do you expect the monad to do for you?

Comment: @amalloy <facepalm>

Comment: @K.A.Buhr. I want to add a monad instance that takes the elements out of the environment (Env :: [(String, Value)] ) and it creates an application :@: term from it. This way the variables have values in a list and you can use them in expressions.

Comment: It sounds like you want a reader monad. This won't have an instance for `Expr`, rather your `eval` will have a type like `eval :: Expr -> Reader Env Value`. Then your `Env` gets threaded through the calls without needing to be passed explicitly for every recursive call.

Comment: Do you want the monadic bind to substitute variables? If so, then you need an `Expr a` with `Var a` instead of `Expr` with `Var String`.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, your `eval (ef :@: ae)` case is wrong, since you're using the wrong copy of `env` in evaluating `ef` and `ea`.  You want this instead:

```
eval (ef :@: ea)    env = let FunVal env' var body = eval ef env
                              arg                  = eval ea env
                           in eval body ((var,arg):env')
```

Anyway, let's start by discussing the usual way of "using a monad" for an evaluation function like `eval`.

Your `eval` function has signature:

```
eval :: Expr -> Env -> Value
```

Even though it's *primary* purpose is to take an `Expr` and determine its `Value` (i.e., it's basically a function `Expr -> Value`), you have some extra information you need to carry around, namely this `Env` that describes variable bindings.  Even though you only access these bindings when processing `Var` and `Sub` constructors and only modify these bindings when processing `:@:` constructors, you still need to pass `Env` around for all the cases that don't care about it, especially cases like:

```
eval (Bin e1 op e2) env = applyIntOp op (eval e1 env) (eval e2 env)
```

which don't even *touch* `env`, but need to pass it along to every recursive `eval` call.

To avoid this, what folks usually do is introduce a monadic context for their evaluation.  This does **not** involve writing a monad instance for `Expr` or `Env` or `Value`.  Rather, it involves changing the signature of `eval` to take an `Expr` and return a `Value`, but in a "monadic context" that can make `Env` available for inspection and modification:

```
evalM :: Expr -> MyMonad Value
```

There's a actually a ready-made monad for this, so you don't have to write your own:

```
import Control.Monad.Reader
type MyMonad = Reader Env
```

After this, it's somewhat easier to write the cases that don't care about `Env`:

```
evalM (Lit i) = pure $ IntVal i
evalM (Bin e1 op e2) = applyIntOp op <*> eval e1 <*> eval e2
```

and the cases that *do* care about `Env` don't look too bad either:

```
evalM (Var v) = asks (fromJust . lookup v)
evalM (Abs v b) = FunVal <$> ask <*> pure v <*> pure b
evalM (ef :@: ea) = join $ apply <$> evalM ef <*> evalM ea
  where apply (FunVal env var body) va =
          local (const ((var,va):env)) $ evalM body
```

Admittedly, introducing `MyMonad` doesn't help very much in this example, but if you decided to extend your language to support mutable values, error handling, and IO side effects, you'd start to see more advantages to this approach.

Again, this is the **usual** way of using a monad for evaluation, but I'm not sure if this is what you were asking about or not.

An **unusual** way of using a monad for evaluation would be to write a monad instance for an `Expr` type where the monadic action is some kind of "substitution".  It's really hard to imagine how this would work.  The most obvious starting point would be to consider the way a monad is often used to recursively replace elements of a structure without changing the overall structure.  For example, the list monad can be viewed as replacing each element of a list with a new list, but instead of returning a list of lists, it concatenated it all together to give it the same type as the origin.  For trees with values at the leaves, there's a usual monad that replaces each leaf with an associated tree, but instead of giving a tree of trees, the structure is flattened out so it's just a tree of the same type as the original.

From this starting point, it's easy to imagine a substitution monad for expressions where the leaves are the variable references:

```
data ExprM a
  =  LitM Integer
  |  VarM a
  |  BinM (ExprM a) Op (ExprM a)
  deriving (Show, Functor)
```

The monadic action can be to substitute each `VarM a` (leaf) with an `ExprM a` (tree):

```
instance Applicative ExprM where
  pure = VarM
  (<*>) = ap
instance Monad ExprM where
  VarM x >>= f = f x
  LitM n >>= f = LitM n
  BinM e1 op e2 >>= f = BinM (e1 >>= f) op (e2 >>= f)
```

Note that there is no `AppM` constructor because it's been replaced by the monadic bind.  If you want to substitute `LitM 1` for the value of `VarM "x"` in the expression `BinM (VarM "x") Plus (VarM "x")`, you do it like so:

```
body1 = BinM (VarM "x") Plus (VarM "x")

context1 "x" = LitM 1
context1 _ = error "variable not found"

example1 = body1 >>= context1
```

which gives:

```
> example1
BinM (LitM 1) Plus (LitM 1)
```

The problem is that it's not at all clear how to add the `Abs` constructor back in.  It can't really have form:

```
... | Abs a (ExprM a) | ...
```

because the only sensible monad instance would have to perform substitution on the *argument name*, which doesn't make any sense.  It would also be susceptible to variable capture.

If there's some clever representation for `Abs` that lets you stick with a monadic substitution scheme, I'm not seeing it.